# How to do a non-recurring timeout in Gtk#?

Tags: mono, gtk#

I'm trying to do a thing a second in the future, but only once. [The docs for GLib.Timeout.Add](http://docs.go-mono.com/monodoc.ashx?link=M%3aGLib.Timeout.Add) say that the "delegate is invoked repeatedly until it returns `false`", so I'm returning `false` and then I get an error from glib.

Example code:

```
using System;

class foo {
  static void Main() {
    Gtk.Application.Init();

    uint t = GLib.Timeout.Add(1000, () => {
      Console.WriteLine("returning false from timeout");
      Gtk.Application.Quit();
      return false;
    });
    Console.WriteLine("timeout added with source id = {0}", t);

    Gtk.Application.Run();
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
$ mono foo.exe
timeout added with source id = 6
returning false from timeout

(foo:19030): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 6 was not found when attempting to remove it
```

How do I stop my timeout from repeating after it times out without getting errors?

```
$ pkg-config --modversion gtk-sharp-3.0
2.99.3
```

Note that the error message apparently appears at program exit, and in my real program it does not seem to appear until the gc runs (I can get it immediately after the timeout if I manually call the gc and wait for finalizers).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. The timeout won't repeat because it has been properly removed. That's what the "error" is from because the gtk runtime is trying to dispose the timeout twice. This issue isn't just the C# gtk implementation, it's a bug in the C gtk+ library. There is a way to disable gtk from reporting errors, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I don't think the C GTK library has this bug, as timeout functions aren't objects that need to be disposed in C. The rest of what you say makes sense, though. You might be able to work around it by returning `true` instead, since the main loop will stop anyway when you call `Application.Quit()` and the timeout won't be called again.